# Is batch normalisation a nonlinear operation?

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

Can batch normalisation be considered a nonlinear operation like relu or sigmoid?

I have come across a resnet block like:

```
: IBasicBlock(
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (prelu): PReLU(num_parameters=512)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
```

so I wonder if batchnormalisation can act as non linear operation

Comment: No, batchnorm has very different behaviors and purpose than activation functions like `sigmoid` or `relu` (or `prelu` in this case) . And once the training is done, its mean and variant remain frozen and it becomes a completely affine transformation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch Normalization is non-linear *in the data points x<sub>i</sub>* on a per batch training basis, but is linear during inference in the scaling parameters (as these are fixed).

Comment: (+1) I don't know why there is so much inconsistency of definition between mathematics and deep learning. The correct term should be affine, not linear. Can't fight the wind.